# Crackling Sound Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: dual-boot, soundcard

I recently did a dual boot to my pc, but I've been having some issues with the sound. Every time I play music or a video, my speaker starts to do a weird noise, like crackling and beeps.

`My sound card is: HDA Intel PCH`

`My chip is: Realtek ALC3241`

Answer (score 0):

Could be the speech-dispatcher in your sound settings. Try muting or disabling it. See here:

[image: sound settings]